# Accessing nested array in $refs

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-maps, vue.js, geolocation

I'm using the vue-googlemaps package to get a list of restaurants. I want to filter the list with matching records in my database. I can access this.$refs.results in the mounted hook by doing the following.

```
    mounted () {
      console.log(this.$refs.results);
    }
```

The result in the console.
[image]

As you can see at the bottom of the image, the results array is populated but as soon as I do the following. I always get null.

```
mounted () {
  console.log(this.$refs.results.results);
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you try `this.$refs.results['results']`?

Comment: I would urge you to use the vuex store instead of this. You´re gona end up using that anyway sooner or later

Comment: It seems that `this.$refs.results.results` is set after the `mounted` hook is called. Console receives an object reference and displays the actual properties only at the moment you expand the  object so if data was modified, you will see the updated props.. If you want to see the actual state of the object at the moment you log it you could do this `console.log((JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.$refs.results)))` ...

Comment: @maxim Thank you dude, really appreciate the help.